# How to make image buttons only appear when listview item is clicked?

Tags: android, listview, imagebutton

Screenshot with no item clicked
[image]

What i want to achieve:
[image]

Comment: you can use `ImgViewBtn.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE)` to show  on clicked item.

Answer (score 0):

This will work:

```
  lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
                        long id) {
                    btn.setVisibility(view.VISIBLE);
                }
            });
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your response :) i'll try this. can i make an imagebutton on top of the layout?